# Devise - Confirmable not sending emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Just to get it out of the way: I do have emails working in my app.

I just added :confirmable to my user model.

**app/models/user.rb**

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
   :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
```

I do have the confirmable part in the db:

**db/schema.rb**

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  ...
  t.string   "confirmation_token"
  t.datetime "confirmed_at"
  t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
end
```

Because of the omniauth I have overwritten `registrations_controller`:

**app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb**

```
def create
  super
  session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record?
end
```

So what I'm trying to figure out is… what do I need to add in order to:

1. Get confirmation email sent after the user signs up
2. <strike>Redirect the user to a custom page explaining the email is waiting to be confirmed (which they would get to if they tried signing in again without confirming)</strike>  (answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463012/rails-3-and-devise-redirecting-to-page-following-signup-confirmable))
3. (should be taken care of automatically?) When the user is verified redirect them to given page

**Update**: Right now, when I create a user it is automatically confirmed. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I didn't realize I had the following in my user model:

```
def send_confirmation_instructions
  # stops Devise from automatically sending a confirmation email
end

def confirmation_required?
  skip_confirmation!
end
```

Commenting them out gets the email to be sent. Still trying to figure out how to redirect after sign in if the user isn't confirmed. And trying to figure out how to properly use confirmation_required?