# Automatic log out in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to make a signup form with devise using the form below

```
    <%= form_for :user , url: user_registration_path do  |f| -%>
      Please add your email adderess to be added to our mailing list
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", :disable_with => 'Submiting...' %>
    <% end -%>
```

however, devise is signing the users in automatically. Please can you advise on how i can sign the users out automatically when the account is created without redirecting them to the sign_out_path or adding a sign out link.

Comment: Why do you use devise for signing up for mailing list?

Comment: This is to allow me easily convert them to user accounts when the application is ready. This is just a sign up form

Comment: I will probably just save the email and then invite them to sign up like everyone else but you can have your way. Take a look at admin confirmable on devise wiki.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the after_signup_path_for(resource) method as shown in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5466245/367869. In that method you could make a call to something like

```
sign_out current_user
```

However, I do agree with user136060's comment to your question - if all you're doing is a mailing list, Devise is probably overkill.